# PVS Studio on Linux - command line return codes

Tags: pvs-studio

[Official documentation](https://www.viva64.com/en/m/0035/#ID0E6IAI) for Windows command line is quite clear - return code is a bit mask, every bit means something and, particularly, code '256' means 'some issues were found in the source code'.

For the Linux command line operation I can get this help message wih `pvs-studio-analyzer --help`

```
pvs-studio-analyzer state codes that form a bit mask exit code are:
  0 - Analysis was successfully completed, no issues
      were found in the source code;
  1 - Preprocessing failed on some file(s);
  2 - Indicates that analyzer license will expire in
      less than a month;
  3 - Analysis was interrupted;
  4 - Error (crash) during analysis of some source file(s);
  5 - Indicates that analyzer license has expired;
  6 - License expiration warning suppression flag was used
      with non-expiring license;
```

First of all, these codes can not form a valid bit mask, they are not powers of 2!
Secondly, there is no specific return code meaning "some issues were found in the source code" in which I'm particularly interested - so there is no obvious way to check if any issues were found (and react to it somehow).

Thirdly, I could not find anything about return codes on Linux in official documentation.

So, my question is - is this help message correct? And if it is, how can I check if any issues were found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pvs-studio-analyzer` utility for Linux and macOS really doesn't return a bit mask. We fixed the description.

To detect cases when there are warnings in the report, use the `plog-converter` utility:

```
plog-converter ... --indicate-warnings ...
```

> -w, --indicate-warnings. Set this option to detect the presense of analyzer warnings after filtering analysis log by setting the
>   converter exit code to '2'.

Comment: Just to clarify: if plog-converter output format is `errorfile` - all issues will be "errors" or there are "warnings" as well?

Comment: @Amomum, `errorfile` is type of report. You have to pass the `--analyzer` param in order to set a level of warnings (Error, Warning, Note).

Comment: So there can be only errors or only warnings or only notes?

Comment: No. For example `-a "GA:1,2,3"`. You can combine levels.

Comment: Oh, okay. So `--indicate-warnings` will return exit code `2` if there was an issue of any level or just for warnings?

Comment: Yes. You're right. `plog-converter` indicates about any issue. The `-a` param is a filter.